# SocketIO send message to client via API route

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a route in my `express` API where I want to emit messages using a *websocket* to a client. In this case, the client is another Node.js app. In this Node.js app, I try to connect to the socket and print messages received. Both the API and the Node app are on different ports. Can someone help me make this work?

Here's how I pass my socket to my express routes:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server on port ${PORT}`);
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server);
app.set("socketio", io);
```

Here's my REST API route:

```
exports.getAll = function(req,res){
    var io = req.app.get('socketio');
    io.emit('hi!');
}
```

Here's my socket io client, it uses `socket.io-client`

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on("message", data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Unfortunately, I don't receive the 'hi' message from my API.

When I call `/api/getAll` I don't receive the message in my client app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When emitting an event via `socket.io` you have you define the event name before the data.
Example:

```
exports.getAll = function(req, res){
    var io = req.app.get("socketio");
    io.emit("message", "hi!");
}
```

Now you'll be able to receive the `message` event from the client.

Reference:

- https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/